Python C++ extension DLL is not imported in python interpreter
I have written a Python extension in C/C++ to wrap my code for Python.
I followed CPython documentation in the parts of C/C++ functions each module should provide
For example, my module contains:
/* This is the initialization function that is called when the module is loaded */
__declspec(dllexport) PyObject* PyInit_spam(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&spammodule);
}

Then I successfuly  compile .dll file, with this file in it (dumpbin result):
   FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001195 PyInit_spam = @ILT+400(PyInit_spam)

Then I rename the dll into pyd, as it is suggested here: Renaming dll to pyd
Also I checked that  dll is x64 with Notepad++, as my Python is.
However it is not loaded into the Python interpreter
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_spam)

Would be very grateful for help
